# Xcode 11.1: Test indicators not shown

Tags: xcode, xcode11

With the latest Xcode AppStore version (11.1), and a freshly configured project & workspace, the test indicators are not updated after testing. This means: the remain black and empty, as shown in the attachement.

Does anyone else have this problem? Has anyone any idea how to fix this (if not to be fixed by Apple because it's a bug)? (Cleaning up project, removing derived data folder etc. had no effect; it's also independent of classic project or SwiftUI project.)

[image]

[Edit:] This is also true for the newest Xcode Beta 11.2 beta (11B41).

Comment: ...as well as for Xcode 12 beta 2.